# why in rxjs will an observable not seen as such unless I use the from function?

Tags: node.js, rxjs

this is a question to understand a bit more about rxjs and how observables are handled. 
I am connecting to my db in my db module and on completion I return an observable for my main module.

```
    connectToDB: function () {
    return new Observable(
        (observer) => {
            sql.connect((err, result) => {
                if (err) return err;
                observer.next(result);
                observer.complete();
            });
        }

    );
}
```

in my main application I am listening to the observable and then making some queries once it's connected like so:

```
from(db.connectToDB).switchMap((isConnected)=>{
        const surveyQuestions = db.queryDB("//QUERY"); //this function is exactly the same as connectToDb, only difference is that I return the result of the query
    });
```

What I don't understand is why if I'm returning an observable in my db module why I need to use the from function in my main module? I thought that if I'm returning an observable I wouldn't need from. But if don't use it node won't see it as an observable. Is there any explanation for it? Or am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

The `from()` creation method is used to create an Observable from Promises, arrays and so on... but not a function that returns an Observable. This means that the following code won't work:

```
const func = () => of(42);

from(func).subscribe(console.log); // error
```

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-uefr6q?file=index.ts

So there're two things:

- You don't need to be using `from` at all. Just chain `db.connectToDB().switchMap(...).subscribe(...)`
- If what you have right now works then it looks like you're overriding `db.connectToDB` with its return value somewhere because this shouldn't work as you can see in the example above.

Comment: I tried the db.connectToDB().switchMap, but it actually throws this error TypeError: db.connectToDB.switchMap is not a function . And the program is just what I just written here, nothing more for now. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Did you import `switchMap`?

Comment: yes I did, will work only if I wrap db.ConnectToTB with from. That's what I found weird

Comment: Then it doesn't look like `db.ConnectToTB` is a function.

Comment: it is, it's the code written in my question. Could it be that since is an imported function from a different module, make the difference

Comment: I don't know your code but you can see in the demo that `from` doesn't work with functions.

Comment: that's so weird.